# Jupiter, unable to reset data frame index

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image]

The above table is obtained after filtering dataframe (df).

As mentioned below, When I tried to remove old index it give no result,

```
df2.head(n=6).reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not chain `reset_index()` and `inplace=True` with filter function

```
df = df.rename(dict(zip(df.index[:6],range(6)))
```

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge what you mean no output here ?